# Rails: How do I organize these?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm having a hard time organizing each product like a gallery. Can you help me figure this out, all help would be appreciated.

```
  <% @products.each do |product| %>
          <%= product.title %> 
          <%= product.edition %> 
          <%= link_to (image_tag product.image.url(:large)), product %>

          <%= product.price %>

  <% end %>
```

This is how id like them to be organized.

[image]

Comment: What does your CSS look like and how is it coming out now?

Comment: @steve klein I dont have much in my css. If I put in the code from bootstrap it looks great. But if I put my code in the there it starts to not be allied. Not sure if its because of the image size

Comment: Can you update your post with your code?  Generally, if you just display images they should align like that.  You can add styling for margin etc. like [so](https://jsfiddle.net/bkrb5x6r/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use bootstrap's grid system, http://getbootstrap.com/css/ with ruby's each_slice method

Answer (score 1):

Something like the below should work:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
       <h1 class="page-header">Thumbnail Gallery</h1>
    </div>
    <% @products.each do |product| %>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-6 thumb">
           <%= link_to product.image.url(:large), product do %>       
               <%= image_tag product.image %>
               <%= product.title %> 
               <%= product.edition %>
               <%= product.price %>

           <% end %>
      </div> 
  </div>
<% end %>
</div>
</div>
```

This is taken from the example HTML at https://github.com/IronSummitMedia/startbootstrap-thumbnail-gallery/blob/gh-pages/index.html

The css is provided entirely by Twitter Bootstrap, which I assume you've already include in your project.

I added product.image with html generated by an image_tag as well. You didn't have an image in your erb.

Comment: I got an error saying `undefined method stringify_keys' for #<Product:0x007f90385bec60>`